# Detect Prestashop Temp & Plugins

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.6

I have a question about PrestaShop.
How can i detect which template and plugin/modules are using in a PrestShop site?

For example [**this**](http://www.krisvanassche.com/) site. I couldnt find the details on source code (for template name, it writes kva; but i think its a fake name. i dont think they use full custom template)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The theme name is "kva" and since the shop is called KrisVanAssche.com this most probably is custom theme. The only modules that you can know about are the ones that include .css and .js (in case of CCC is not enabled - which is the case in that site). So in the current case you can see that they use the feeder module, the paypal module and the cron module. Additionaly from the CCC JS & CSS you can see that they are using blockcart & blockuserinfo. That's all.